# Is there a way for a progressive web app to save a lot of data without using up all the memory?

Tags: javascript, filesystems, progressive-web-apps, indexeddb, offline-storage

what i'm trying to do is save (2GB +-) of data for offline use. i do this using Dexie( wrapper for indexeddb) for my Progressive web app.

My problem is that i use all of my laptops/android/IOS device's memory(RAM).

Is there a way for a progressive web app to save a lor of data without using up all the memory?

-localstorage has limits i think and also relies on memory or am i wrong ?
-Filesystem API is it possible ?
-LargeLocalStorage is it possible ? (https://github.com/tantaman/LargeLocalStorage)[image][image]
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure which one you mean with memory. RAM or Hard Drive.

Comment: The best APIs are indeed IndexedDB, and Cache for responses, especially files. If that takes up lots of RAM, it's probably because 1) you're using Chrome 2) you have a memory leak (not revoking ObjectURL, keeping references to all the data you store in the DB…)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using LargeLocalStorage, because that's an old project that uses old APIs which are not in use today (for example WebSQL in Safari).

### Solution for saving big files

[I do recommend you to stay with IndexedDB](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/web-storage/offline-for-pwa), since it's widely supported (more than the Filesystem API which is only supported in Chrome). 
However, each of the browsers might limit you in the data that you can store **per origin** (and not per api, which can help you). In Chrome for example it's up to 6% from your device free space. In the link I've attached you can find more details. Of course, you can use the [StorageQuota API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StorageQuota) to learn more about how much space you have left.

### Inspecting memory usage

If you meant memory as RAM and not HDD/SSD - I would suggest inspecting the memory in your device using [Chrome dev tools](http://chrome://inspect/#devices). You can [inspect Chrome on your device](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging) using Chrome on your workstation. Afterwards, [profile your memory](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems) and try to see what is using all of it

Comment: ok thank you i will stay with indexeddb but as you said it takes up all of my memory/RAM all the data gets saved there but it is too much data for mobile devices and even my laptop. Is there a way too save the data elsewhere instaid of my RAM

Comment: Can you please describe what you see in your memory profiling? 
IndexdDB stores the data on the HDD/SSD, so this shouldn't happen to you

Comment: it's almost all "internal array" with no reference to my code

Comment: Thank you for adding the image :). 
In the image that you have added it seems that your heap is only ~10MB. Are you sure that this tab is consuming all the memory? What are the most RAM consuming processes in your device right now? How much RAM do they use?

Comment: it is defently this tab in chrome ( i have a lot of other chrome tabs open but that should not be a problem)